# Django query returning too many values

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a list of the names in a table using Django. The field I'm searching for is "name", and I print out my response, which gives the following:

```
[u"name1", u"name2"]
```

However, when I send that to a website in javascript, I see that the length is 16, though console.log shows the same result as the python print statements. When I try to iterate over the list that prints as above, I get the integers 0-15 (the loop I am using is 
`for (var name in names)`).

Why is the string representation of this list so much different than the actual representation, and how do I get a representation that matches the print representation if I can't iterate over it or anything?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What about showing us the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `names` is actually a string within your javascript. You need to pass back the json list or convert the stringified json into objects. This second part can be done with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Unfortunately, your question doesn't show how you're returning the data or how you're handling the data within javascript, so I can't help you any further than this for now.

Comment: That was actually the issue, I haven't parsed it from a string yet.